# Show that $(C+DD^{T})^{-1}=C^{-1}D(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$(C+DD^{T})^{-1}=C^{-1}D(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)^{-1}$$

I took the inverse of both sides.

$$((C+DD^{T})^{-1})^{-1}=(C^{-1}D(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)^{-1})^{-1}$$
$$C+DD^{T}=(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)(C^{-1}D)^{-1}$$

After this I got stuck, what else can I do?

Comment: Do you already have the fact that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C+DD^{T}=(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)(C^{-1}D)^{-1} \implies C+DD^{T}=(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)(D^{-1}C) \implies C+DD^{T}= D^{-1}C + D^{T}$.

Your identity is missing some thing.

Answer (score 0):

The identity should be
$$ (C+DD^T)^{-1} = C^{-1} D (I+D^T C^{-1} D)^{-1} D^{-1} $$
(otherwise the powers of $D$ don't make sense for the first term in the bracket, for one thing)

Starting on the left,
$$\begin{align}
(C+DD^T)^{-1} &= ((I+DD^TC^{-1})C)^{-1} \\
&= C^{-1} (I+DD^T C^{-1})^{-1} \\
&= C^{-1} DD^{-1}(I+DD^T C^{-1})^{-1} \\
&= C^{-1}D (D+DD^T C^{-1}D)^{-1} \\
&= C^{-1}D (D(I+D^T C^{-1} D))^{-1} \\
&= C^{-1} D (I+D^T C^{-1} D)^{-1} D^{-1}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify whether $A^{-1}=B$, it's sufficient to verify that $AB=I$ (the identity matrix). Now
$$
(C+DD^{T})C^{-1}D(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)^{-1}=I
$$
if and only if
$$
(C+DD^{T})C^{-1}D=I+D^{T}C^{-1}D
$$
that is,
$$
D+DD^TC^{-1}D=I+D^TC^{-1}D
$$
which is obviously false, in general. Just take $C=I$ and $D=2I$: the left hand side is $10I$, the right hand side is $5I$.

If you want to prove instead that
$$
(C+DD^{T})^{-1}=C^{-1}D(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)^{-1}\color{red}{D^{-1}}
$$
this is equivalent to
$$
(C+DD^{T})C^{-1}D(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)^{-1}D^{-1}=I
$$
that is equivalent to
$$
(C+DD^{T})C^{-1}D(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)^{-1}=D
$$
hence to
$$
(C+DD^{T})C^{-1}D=D(I+D^{T}C^{-1}D)
$$
which is obviously true.